# Multiple data shown from database into same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Controller:**

```
private void FetchData()
        {
           //Reinicia a varíavel addresses se já conter algo
                if (addresses.Count > 0)
                {

                    addresses.Clear();
                }
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    com.Connection = con;
                    com.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [SYSTEM_NAME], [SYSTEM_STATUS], [SYSTEM_SHORTMSG] FROM [CORE_SYS_STATUS]";
                    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                    //Lê os dados da base de dados 
                        addresses.Add(new GestaoAlertas()
                        {
                            ID = (int)dr["ID"]
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_NAME = dr["SYSTEM_NAME"].ToString()
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_STATUS = dr["SYSTEM_STATUS"].ToString()
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_SHORTMSG = dr["SYSTEM_SHORTMSG"].ToString()

                        });
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    }
              //Mostra o erro se houver um
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   throw ex;
                }
        }
```

**My view:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(addresses);
        }
```

I was wondering how do i put more data (different table) into the Index view, i tried doing a addresses2 but it doesn't make sense because I can't put it on the "return View()".

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a view model

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public List<Address> Adresses {get; set;}
      public List<Address> Adresses2 {get; set;}
}
```

action

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     var model=new AddressViewModel {Address= new List<Address>, Address= new List<Address> };
      FetchData(model.Address);
      FetchData(model.Address2);
      return View(model);
 }


private void FetchData(List<Address> adresses)
 {
.....
}
```

view

```
@model AddressViewModel
.....
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is send a model to the view. The model will contain all the data. And then in the view (cshtml) you can extract the data from the model and render as needed.

For example:

```
Public class Payload
{
    List<Address> addresses1 {get; set;}
    List<Address> addresses2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the **action** do the followings:

```
Payload = new Payload();
Payload.addresses1 = FetchData(); //Change the logic to load data of address1 as a list
Payload.addresses2 = FetchData(); //Change the logic to load data of address2 as a list

return View(Payload);
```

In the **View** (cshtml):
Add the view model type in the page (first line):

```
@model Payload
```

You can also add necessary using statement like:

```
@using MyProject.Payload;
```

Then render data as needed:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    @foreach (var addr in Model.addresses1)
    {
       //Render address1 data
    }

    @foreach (var addr in Model.addresses2)
    {
       //Render address2 data
    }
}
```